# Any Code scanning tool for Xquery language

Tags: teamcity, xquery, marklogic, checkmarx

Is there any Code scanning tool available for XQuery language which can be integrated with teamcity.

We are currently using Checkmarx but it do not support XQuery language.

Comment: What do you want the code scanning tool to do? Is it about looking for security vulnerabilities?

Comment: @MichaelKay this is a totally off-topic comment. I just want to say that your XSLT Programmer's reference book helped me A LOT in the early stages of my career! Thank you, sir!

Comment: @MichaelKay yes, need to scan for security vulnerabilities and sensitive data

Comment: The general technique for XSLT and XQuery is not to scan the code to see whether it's doing anything it shouldn't, but rather to execute it in an environment where it can't do anything it shouldn't, for example by disabling access to external resources.